# How to use 3rd party extention in Joomla JA Purity III?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, extensions, t3-framework, purity-iii

I'm trying to use [JPro Final Countdown](http://joomla-pro.org/jpro-final-countdown) extension in my Purity template. I use quickstart and modified it as I want. I already installed the extension and set up the configuration in `JPro Final Countdown` module. I don't know what to do next to makes my countdown shown in front page.

I already read [documentation about installing 3rd party](https://www.joomlart.com/documentation/purity-iii/compatible-third-party-extensions#supported-extension). From what I understand is that if I want to use 3rd party extension besides the supported extension, I have to create `.less` file in `templates/purity_iii/less/extras`. The question is:

1. What would be inside the `.less` file? or I just have to leave it empty?
2. After I created the `.less` file, how do I assign it to my style?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do not confuse USING, CONFIGURING and STYLING 3rd party extension!

Nothing (and certainly not a template) is preventing you to USE JPro Final Countdown module, if you have installed it correctly and assigned it to correct template position and menu item(s).

You can also CONFIGURE it as per varous available parameters in module's configuration back end in Joomla admin.

Now, STYLING it is another story, and that is what is documentation you mentioned reffering to. Changing module's visual appearance is what is Styling all about, and it is done by applying and adjusting certain CSS selectors. Using `.less` files is just modern approach to good-old CSS styling, and if you are not pretty experienced in CSS, it might be more complicated and pretty frustrating.

You dont even have to follow JA documentation in order to change module's CSS selectors. Much easier is to, if you haven't already, create empty file `custom.css` in folder `/templates/purity_iii/css/`, then add to it any module-specific selector and adjust it to your liking.

Now, main question is how good are you with CSS, and that question is even more applicable for dealing with LESS.

---

**UPDATE**

---

From your comment I now realize that you need help with most basic actions in using Joomla, such as configuring module to appear on specific page. While I could recommend some great Tutorials, best of which are [OSTraining Joomla 3 Classes](https://www.ostraining.com/classes/joomla/), I am sure you can find 'em with a little help of your Google. So, I will list some basic steps for configuring this countdown module you want to show on front page.

1. Go to `Extensions | Modules`, find `JPro Final Countdown` module, click on it to edit it.
   In `Module` tab set Position to `masthead` and Status to `Published`. Configure other fields as per your liking (Show Title to Hide, Welcome Text, etc...)

[image: Module config]

2. In `Menu Assignement` tab choose `Only on the pages selected` as module assignement, then click on `Select:None` to clear all checkboxes first, and finally check only `Features Intro 2` menu item in `Main Menu|Layouts|New Layots` menu, which is default menu item (Home item) in Purity III Quickstart.
   Of course, if you have re-assigned default menu item, then select that item accordingly.

[image: Menu assignement]

3. Click `Save and Close` button, and on front end you will see your module at the top of the page, right below toolbar. Please note that the following screenshot was made by adding `?tp=1` to show available module positions in template (after enabling that in `Extensions|Templates - Options buton` ).

[image: Frontend with tp=1]

Now, there are many other things which can be done for configuring and styling this module, but these are just basic steps to make it visible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already installed the 3rd party and configure the module. I just need a clear step to make it appear on the front page...

Comment: I see... Please check my updated answer...

Comment: Thank you so much for super clear explanation, sir. Another question, can I put this module into specific article? I'm using `Features Intro 1 Layout` (http://purity-iii.demo.joomlart.com/index.php/layout/new-layouts/features-intro) and I want to put the module in `Fully responsive` article. How would I do that? @Mikan

Comment: You are welcome, but if you keep asking Qs without accepting good As which have helped you (you have alrady asked 'How to customize background image and youtube window in Purity III - Features Intro 1' on Nov. 29 under different user account), you will accomplish just two things: 1. JSE will keep your Qs as opened and other users won't know they already have good As which can help them too, and 2. No one will bother to answer them, because here on JSE we show our gratitude by accepting and upvoting posts which helped us. Also, there is limit to one Q per post, so please ask another question.

Comment: At that time I immediately upvote your answer but JSE says `Thank you for the feedback, vote cast by those with less then 15 reputation are recorded but don't change the publicly display score`. So I guess it's a mark that the answer is useful for me although I didn't comment "thanks" for your answer. Sorry for my bad attitude. I'll behave better next time.

Comment: Everybody can accept good answer on their question, even with REP 1, by clicking checkmark button below downvote arrow. I see you have found it. And JSE is all about helping each other. Cheers... :-)

Comment: I can't see any checkmark button below downvote arrow, that's why I just upvote your answer. And again, I'm so sorry for bad attitude.

Comment: That's OK, we all need some time to learn using JSE, I for one still learn new things about it after year and a half of using it daily.